# Jquery UI Tabs : bug - when mouse hover is selected

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

i found the following bug when using jquery ui tabs ,

when i selected the event as mouse hover and added animation to it

```
$("#Tab").tabs({ "event":"mouseover",fx:{ opacity: 'toggle' , duration:'slow'}});
```

when i move the mouse over the tabs quickly , two tab contents remain open at the same time .

this is the bug confirmed , check this

http://jsbin.com/iyubo

i think the problem is that **Jquery UI Tabs is not using hover intent** , any solution this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Dont hover over them quickly! hehe :)

I think the best solution would be to set a js variable with the last-but-one hovered item, and then after a timeout of idle period, to trigger the mouseout of this "last-but-one" hovered tab, something of say 50 ms. You might be able to play around with the stop() function on the tabs aswell, this might help.

That's a rough idea, but if users are being silly then why should you cater for them! - Will it even happen? :)